# Laravel insert on DB not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem on insert into DB with information coming from a blade form. The system is not sending to the DB and it doesn't actually through any sense error. It all seems ok and i cant find a possible mistake. Any clue on what might be happening?

This is my blade:

```
                            {!! Form::open(['method'=>'post', 'action'=>'AdminTasksController@store']) !!}

                                <div class="form-group' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::select('category_id',[''=>'Chose categories'] + $categories,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::select('job_id',[''=>'Chose job type'] + $jobs,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <input type="hidden" name="house_id" value="{{Auth::user()->house->id}}">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::select('user_id',[''=>'Chose user'] + $users->toArray(),null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::number('task_priority', null, ['placeholder'=>'Task Priority', 'min'=>1, 'max'=>10]) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::date('task_expire', null, ['placeholder'=>'Expire date']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            Register
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is my controller method on AdminTasksController:

```
public function store(Request $request){


        Task::create($request->all());

        return redirect('/admin/task');


    }
```

This is my router, the problem might be coming from here, but just in case:

```
//tasks
Route::get('/admin/task', 'AdminTasksController@index')->name('admin/task');
Route::get('/admin/task/create', 'AdminTasksController@create')->name('admin/task/create');
Route::get('/admin/task/store', 'AdminTasksController@store')->name('admin/task/store');

Route::get('/user/task', 'AdminTasksController@userIndex')->name('user/task');
```

Comment: Try changing `action'=>'AdminTasksController@store'` to `action="/admin/task/store"` and the Route from get to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this route to `Route::post`:

```
Route::post('/admin/task/store', 'AdminTasksController@store')->name('admin/task/store');
```